# Matrix formulas

Tags: matrices

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative field, $n ∈ \mathbb{N}^{*}$ fixed. For $A = (a_{i,j})_{1≤i,j≤n} ∈ M_{n}(k)$, we set

$$\tilde{P}_{A}(X) = \det(A + XI_{n} ).$$
where $I_{n}$ is the identity matrix of $M_{n}(k)$. we write

$$\tilde{P}_{A}(X) = P_{0}(A)X^n + P_{1}(A)X^{n-1} + ... + P_{n-1}(A)X + P_{n}(A)$$

and we give that $P_{0}(A) = 1,\;P_{1}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} = T_{r}(A)$ and $P_{n}(A) = \det(A)$

in the following, we set $\mathbb{K}'= \mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{K}[X])$ the field of the fractions of $\mathbb{K}[X].$ For $R ∈ \mathbb{K}^{'}$ and

$P(X) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}X^{i} ∈ \mathbb{K}[X]$. we naturally denote by $P(R) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}R^{i}$

a)  show that if $A$ is invertible $B = A^{-1}$, then we have

$$\tilde{P}_{B}(X) = \frac{1}{\det(A)}X^{n}\tilde{P}_{A}(\frac{1}{X})$$

b)deduce that when $A$ is invertible we have:

$$tr(A^{-1})\cdot \det(A) = P_{n-1}(A)$$

please can someone help with those two question i thought that if i take in consideration that $tr$ is linear that would help me, but i can't go further, can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

For a) note that:
\begin{align}
\tilde{P}_B(X)&=\det(B+XI_n)\\
&=\det(A^{-1})\det(I_n+XA)\\
&=\det(A)^{-1}\det\left(X\left(\frac{1}{X}I_n+A\right)\right)\\
&=\det(A)^{-1}X^n\det\left(A+\frac{1}{X}I_n\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\det(A)}X^n\tilde{P}_A\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)
\end{align}
Now b) follows from the formula in a) by comparing the coefficient of $X^{n-1}$ on both sides.

Comment: thank you so much yeah i got it now in b)do i have to start by $X^{n} \geq X^{n - 1}$ ??

Comment: What do you mean by $X^n\geq X^{n-1}$?

Comment: because i really don't know how i can introduce tr()

Comment: $Tr(B)$ is the coefficient of $X^{n-1}$ in $\tilde{P}_B(X)$ as you wrote in your question.

Comment: yeah yeah thank you so much i'm really sorry